# How do I specify a path to an executable for a systemd unit file on nix?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, nixos, mkdir, nix

I'm trying to write a systemd unit file.

How do I specify the path to an executable? How can I determine what to use?

In this specific case I'm trying to use `mkdir`.

```
ExecStartPre = "/bin/mkdir -p %h/.config/example/pending/";
```

This results in a error when starting the unit file though:

```
Jan 16 08:46:11 nixos systemd[19577]: example.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/mkdir: No such file or directory
```

---

I suppose I could just use `which` to find the path to mkdir - but I'm seeing a `${pkgs.nameOfPackage}` in other's nix's config - so possibly I should be using this instead?

```
which mkdir
/run/current-system/sw/bin/mkdir
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, `${pkgs.nameOfPackage}` is the preferred syntax.

For your specific examplem `mkdir` is part of the coreutils package; which (pun intended) you can determine with the command `readlink $(which mkdir)`. So your line should read:

```
ExecStartPre=${pkgs.coreutils}/bin/mkdir BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

While coreutils is always installed AFIK, a nice benefit of the `${pkgs.nameOfPackage}` syntax is that you don't need to install the package `nameOfPackage`; Nix will pull it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need those spaces and double quotes.

```
ExecStartPre=/run/current-system/sw/bin/mkdir -p %h/.config/example/pending
```

Secondly, have you tried the command on your system as it is written ?
In your shell:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/example/pending
```

Lastly, %h refers to the user's home. But maybe your system is targeting to another place, since the mkdir command isn't in the right place. `echo ~` to see your home directory.

Comment: Welcome , `mkdir` is under `/run/current-system/sw/bin/` as `which` command say.

Comment: Yes, but there could be a symlink, in which case the /bin/mkdir could work.

Comment: @GAD3R `mkdir` is found first in the OP's $PATH in /run/current-system/sw/bin/ but that doesn't tell us much about where systemd should look.